# My map looks wierd and "pixly" in OL3

Tags: javascript, openlayers

I'm trying to present a mapserver with OL3, it doesnt work well. The documentation of the mapserver is non-existent and the GetCapabilities to the mapserver responds with a very short (not so good or usefull) answer.

I have managed to present the map, but it looks very weird, quite pixly. A picture says more then thousand words, so I'll just present to you how it looks.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/5ZS3s.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/hKzah.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EsCp3.jpg

And I even did a JS fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qpz7bp2g/

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you reference the answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674096/my-map-looks-wierd-and-pixly-in-ol3 ? People with same issue may wonder the answer in the future.

Comment: Got good answer at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26674096/my-map-looks-wierd-and-pixly-in-ol3

It had to do with zoom-levels.